# HANA: Want to include offices that is having 0 value also

Tags: count, hana

I have 4 offices in the table OFFICE_DETAILS which are a,b,c,d.

The below query outputs offices which are having any lab and rad count, so it is including all offices except for c

```
office_name    lab_count   rad_count
 a             5            0
 b             1            2
 d             3            1
```

I want the output to be as follows:

```
 office_name    lab_count   rad_count
 a             5            0
 b             1            2
 c             0            0
 d             3            1
```

what is the change required in the following code

```
SELECT  d.OFFICE_name AS "OFFICE_NAME" ,
   count(CASE 
            WHEN c.LAB_TYPE LIKE 'L' THEN 1
        END) AS "LAB_TEST_COUNT", 
   count(CASE 
            WHEN c.LAB_TYPE in ('X','O') THEN 1
        END) AS "RAD_TEST_COUNT"
FROM 
DOCTOR_CONSULT a
INNER JOIN  consult_labtest b
on(a.CONSULT_ID=b.CONSULT_ID) 
INNER JOIN test_setup c
 on(b.LABTEST_ID=c.TEST_ID)
INNER JOIN OFFICE_DETAILS d
on(a.OFFICE_ID=D.OFFICE_ID)
INNER JOIN USER_SETUP e
on(a.DOCTORS_ID = e.USER_ID)
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT_SETUP f
ON(a.DEPARTMENT_ID = f.DEPARTMENT_ID)
INNER JOIN TEST_CATEGORY g
  ON (c.CATEGORY_ID=g.CATEGORY_ID)
WHERE 
c.LAB_TYPE IN ('L','X','O') --'L'-> Laboratory, 'X'-> Radiology
AND c.ACTIVE_STATUS='Y'
AND d.ACTIVE_STATUS='Y'
AND g.ACTIVE_STATUS='Y'
AND
a.CONSULT_DATE BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE
AND 
d.ACTIVE_STATUS='Y'
AND 
a.EMPLOYEE_ID NOT IN ('NEW RECRUITMENT 380', '0000', 'army', 'undefined')
GROUP BY d.OFFICE_NAME
ORDER BY d.OFFICE_NAME ASC;
```

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve result rows from joined tables that **do not** have matching rows (e.g. no matching entries in `OFFICE_DETAILS` table) SQL provides **OUTER JOINS**.

Join the details tables as outer joins and handle the resulting NULLs in the projection.
This is the most common approach to address this requirement.

Alternatively, the details tables could contain a special “no match” record that is used to match in an `OR` branch of the join condition. Some data warehouses do this to avoid NULLs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found an alternate solution to get the output. I did a LEFT JOIN

Comment: A LEFT JOIN is a type of OUTER join. Your solution is not alternate but identical to the first option in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did by using LEFT JOIN. I am getting the required output

```
CREATE VIEW ECLINIC_KNG.VIEW_LABRADTESTS_OFFICE_COUNT_TODAY AS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS row_num,
   v1.OFFICE_NAME,
   v1.LAB_TEST_COUNT,
   v1.RAD_TEST_COUNT
FROM 
(
 SELECT od.OFFICE_NAME as "OFFICE_NAME",
   (CASE WHEN v.LAB_TEST_COUNT IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE v.LAB_TEST_COUNT END) AS 
  "LAB_TEST_COUNT",
   (CASE WHEN v.RAD_TEST_COUNT IS NULL THEN 0  ELSE v.RAD_TEST_COUNT END) AS 
"RAD_TEST_COUNT"
 FROM 
OFFICE_DETAILS od
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT d.OFFICE_NAME ,
         count(CASE WHEN c.LAB_TYPE LIKE 'L' THEN 1 END) AS "LAB_TEST_COUNT", 
       count(CASE WHEN c.LAB_TYPE in ('X','O') THEN 1 END) AS "RAD_TEST_COUNT"
FROM 
    ECLINIC_KNG.DOCTOR_CONSULT a
    INNER JOIN  ECLINIC_KNG.consult_labtest b
    on(a.CONSULT_ID=b.CONSULT_ID) 
    INNER JOIN ECLINIC_KNG.test_setup c
     on(b.LABTEST_ID=c.TEST_ID)
    INNER JOIN ECLINIC_KNG.OFFICE_DETAILS d
    on(a.OFFICE_ID=D.OFFICE_ID)
    INNER JOIN ECLINIC_KNG.USER_SETUP e
    on(a.DOCTORS_ID = e.USER_ID)
    INNER JOIN ECLINIC_KNG.DEPARTMENT_SETUP f
    ON(a.DEPARTMENT_ID = f.DEPARTMENT_ID)
    INNER JOIN ECLINIC_KNG.TEST_CATEGORY g
      ON (c.CATEGORY_ID=g.CATEGORY_ID)
WHERE 
    c.LAB_TYPE IN ('L','X','O') --'L'-> Laboratory, 'X'-> Radiology
AND c.ACTIVE_STATUS='Y'
AND d.ACTIVE_STATUS='Y'
AND g.ACTIVE_STATUS='Y'
AND a.CONSULT_DATE BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE
AND d.ACTIVE_STATUS='Y'
AND a.EMPLOYEE_ID NOT IN ('NEW RECRUITMENT 380', '0000', 'army', 'undefined')
GROUP BY d.OFFICE_NAME
ORDER BY d.OFFICE_NAME ASC
 )AS v
on(od.OFFICE_NAME=v.OFFICE_NAME)
WHERE od.ACTIVE_STATUS='Y'
ORDER BY od.OFFICE_NAME
)AS v1
```